# Using the [Authorize] keyword is ASP.NET MVC controller stops Script code from running

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authorization, authorize

My JavaScript contained in script tags within my ASP.NET MVC runs perfectly, however, if I add the Authorize keyword in my controller, the JavaScript does not run.  Unfortunately, I haven't found any references to this issue online.

Here is my controller:

```
namespace PROJECT.Controllers
{
   [Authorize]
   public class HomeController : Controller
{
```

The same problem occurs if I add the Authorize keyword on particular controller methods, rather than universally like above.   I'm not sure how to use the Authorize keywork, or an alternative, and enable the JavaScript to run.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is something more than that. The script inside a script tag possibly references other scripts or something. As soon as the script makes it to the browser, it doesn't care if the page that hosts it reqired a cookie to be downloaded.

Comment: After looking into it more, I realized that the issue is when a user is logged in.  When no user is logged in, (and the Authorize tag is commented out) the JavaScript runs.  When a user is logged in, the JavaScript does not run but there are no console errors.

Comment: I would venture to guess that there is a fragment of `JavaScript` in one of your views (or partial views) that is required for the `JavaScript` on the entire page to run. It only takes one `JavaScript` syntax error on the page to disable it and one of your views probably contains the missing fragment to make it syntactically correct. Remove the `[Authorize]` attribute from the `HomeController` and place it on each action method until you find the one that is causing the issue, then check its corresponding view code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you mark an action method with `AuthorizeAttribute`, access to that action method is restricted to users who are both authenticated and authorized. If you mark a controller with the attribute, all action methods in the controller are restricted. Within a controller that is marked with the `AuthorizeAttribute` attribute, you can use the `AllowAnonymousAttribute` attribute to specify that a particular action method is not restricted to only authorized users.

The `Authorize` attribute lets you indicate that authorization is restricted to predefined roles or to individual users. You use the `Roles` and `Users` properties to specify which roles or users are permitted to access the action method. This gives you a high degree of control over who is authorized to view any page on the site.
If an unauthorized user tries to access a method that is marked with the `Authorize` attribute, the MVC framework returns a `401` HTTP status code. If the site is configured to use ASP.NET forms authentication, the `401` status code causes the browser to redirect the user to the login page.

[MSDN Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx).

Comment: I understand the concept.  When the user is logged in after being authenticated, the pages of the site can be viewed and are active.  My issue is that the tag seems to be preventing the JavaScript on these pages, even after authentication.  The JavaScript executes when the Authorize keyword is commented out.

Comment: can you post some javascript example?